# SSRS text skewed when scrolling left and right

Tags: sql, visual-studio, reporting-services

I have uploaded a report that i completed in Visual Studio 2012 to my SSRS server. However, i noticed that when i scroll left or right through the report the text is almost smudged like the image attached. Any advice?
Thanks[image]

Comment: Formatted text, please, not images.

Comment: if you have not deployed your report. Try to download a version from BIDS into excel or pdf format and see if the issue is present.

Answer (score 0):

The default background is transparent. Just set table cell's background to white and the scrolling issue will disappear.

Comment: Please provide a series of steps to better explain how the OP can resolve his issue